# How to disable alt+middle mouse button alternating windows?

Tags: shortcut-keys, ubuntu-studio

I recently installed Ubuntu Studio and every time I press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+middle mouse button, it alternates windows, kinda like <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>.

How can I disable that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found a quick solution for that:

Open Terminal (press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and use this code:

```
xfce4-settings-manager
```

Now go to **Settings Editor**, and under **xfwm4** go to **easy_click** and set the value from *Alt* to *0*.